# Rails route helper not calling to_param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a named route:

```
resources :groups do ... end
```

Groups have an overriden to_param method using the [StringEx gem](https://github.com/rsl/stringex):

```
acts_as_url :name, sync_url: true

def to_param
  url
end
```

And most of the time, I can call it by passing a group in:

```
group_path(g)
```

But sometimes (and I haven't been able to find a clear link on the circumstances) it gives me this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :id=>#<Group id: 121, name: "Example", kind: "ex" ...
```

Really looks like it's not calling to_param, and is just calling to_s or inspect on the group.

Any idea what's going on? This is awfully frustrating.

Comment: Good question.  I've seen this a few times, but I've never really had time to dig into it, just grumbled and called group_path(:id => g.id) or whatever.